# Daisy wheel graphics using the period?

Tags: graphics, printer

Although it would have absolutely beaten the hardware to death, did anyone ever try to write a graphics driver for daisy wheel printers that would use the period symbol to painstakingly construct a graphical image, using micro-step platen and printhead movements?

Due to the speed limitations of the printhead solenoid, such an image would likely have taken 10 times longer to produce than on a 9-pin dot matrix printer, and there is the possibility of damaging the period symbol by over-flexing the wheel support arm. It would be prohibitively expensive with single-use carbon ribbons, and might damage looped fabric ribbons.

But... was it possible and did anyone ever do this?

Answer (score 8):

I used to have a Diablo 630 DWP saved from the dump. This did produce nice graphics using a dot character and micro spacing together with my AT compatible of that time. The whole procedure was, however, not very friendly to both ribbon and paper as you say, you had to reduce wheel impact (by retracting the solenoid) as much as possible to save both from early retirement, and you wanted to use your most faded (fabric) ribbons for that torture. If I remember right, it took several hours to print a 630x350 EGA picture with 4x4 (or 2x2? can't remember) dithering. 300 Baud serial didn't help that much on print speed as well.

You could set the horizontal motion index in 1/120", and the vertical VMI in 1/48", which only allowed printing of pictures turned around by 90°.

Comment: "Saved from Dump in the late 80s" might be an important the clue here. Though, nice hack :))

Comment: @Raffzahn Well, a brand-new 630 cost roughly $2000 in 1985 - You really wouldn't want it to undergo such a torture. I really can't remember well, but think I got it pretty late, in the early 90ies.

Comment: On the other hand, a Diablo 630 is built like a tank - It's probably hard to break it at all. Mine didn't break until the mid-2000s whan I moved house and had to get rid of it

Answer (score 5):

Yes - when at school I wrote a program for the Amstrad PCW that would do this. It's available for download as DSHOWSEA.COM from http://www.seasip.info/Cpm/software/amstrad.html .

The only test I ran was on my geography master's printer: a simple drawing of rectangles. With the dots at their closest spacing, it chewed up the paper rather.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the printer. Also keep in mind, daisy wheel printers aren't anything from before dot matrix, but rather of the same time frame, in general even later. Dot matrix ruled the 70s, while daisy wheels did had their peak during the 80s, until laser took off.

- To start with, not every daisy wheel printer could be positioned (or fed) in size of a dot.
- Next, wear would be outrageous
- A way better and faster printing would be done using more symbols
- Similar, using density of types and multiple strikes produce a way better picture
- And last but not least, who would waste much time to write a driver to wear down a very expensive printer when a cheap dot matrix printer could do a better job?

Having said this, of course have type based printers used for (simple) graphs and drivers have been available, usually in fixed pitch mode.

Comment: I wonder how well a daisy wheel printer could have performed for graphics if one had a wheel containing various combinations of dots?  For example, if one used 15 characters for vertical, horizontal, and diagonal lines that were 1-5 dots long, that would allow a major performance boost for many kinds of graphics.

Comment: And there were definitely text-based graphics done on mainframe line printers, essentially using each character as a pixel with the coverage of the character (@ > X > I > , > . etc.) roughly corresponding to an intensity. See [Mona Lisa](http://q7.neurotica.com/Oldtech/ASCII/Mona.jpg)

Comment: @manassehkatz Isn't that what I mentioned in my 4th point about using type density?

Comment: Sort of except you didn't say it's actually a thing, just a possibility.

Comment: @supercat Keep in mind that the arm is punched onto the paper with constant force, so a multi-dots pattern gets less pressure for the individual dot than a single-dots one, meaning that the single dot will give a deeper black than multi-dots. So, while line graphics would benefit from that approach, greyscale dithering wouldn't give good results.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff: Some printers use plastic one-time ribbons, darkness would be uniform but ribbon usage would be reduced compared with just using periods.  A few other printers from what I understand could vary hammer force electronically.  But if a printer does neither, uniformity would be a problem.

Comment: @manassehkatz: Line printer graphics could also use multiple overstrikes.  If done sufficiently cleverly, it wouldn't have to affect print speed much, though I don't know whether any programmers optimized for that.

Comment: @supercat All daisywheel printers I know regulate hammer impact based on the size of the printed character. This is normally encoded in the daisywheel itself by different spoke forms based on the character area (thus different resistance to the hammer impact). Otherwise, dots would be ending up engraved while "W" or "M" would be too light.

Comment: @tofro: On typed documents, it was quite common for character density to vary with ink area, and I would expect the same to be true with cheap daisy-wheel printers.  Mechanical force compensation would be possible and may have been common, but I would think it would weaken print wheels in ways that would contribute to failure (I've seen daisy wheels wear out from use, though I don't know how common that was).

Comment: @supercat Then your typewriter was broken ;) (Speaking of "cheap daisy-wheel printers":  The Diablo 630 wasn't exactly a bargain...) Actually, there was no weakening of print wheels, rather the opposite - they simply made the spokes of small characters *stronger*.

Comment: @tofro: I'd expect the mass of the print striker to be large relative to the mass of one spoke.  Perhaps many printers engineered their spokes to be stiff enough to absorb a significant fraction of the striker energy, but doing so in a way that would interact nicely with print-head-distance settings would seem like it would significantly increase the moment of inertia for the print wheel compared with making the petals stiff enough merely to hold themselves in position when not struck by the print head.

Comment: For supercat's 1st comment on binary dot encoding, apparently most daisy wheel printers could output up to 96 characters, so a 6-dot tall bit-strip wheel would work (2 ^ 6 = 64 bit patterns). Wheel seek rotation adds print latency, but would likely still have provided a significant speed improvement vs printing each dot row separately..